# Implicit conversion of integers to floats in c

Tags: c, precision

I'm having trouble understading why this code's output is 2147483648:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void){
    float f = 2147483638;
    printf("%f",f);
}
```

I tried to find explanation using IEEE 754 standard for float representation but using my calculations I get that output should be 2147483520, not 2147483648.
Thanks for help!

Comment: If only we knew what the program and the inputs were. Please paste that in the question; don't attempt to link externally.

Comment: Where is "this code"?

Comment: "I get that output should be 2147483520",  Hmm why is that?  Why do you expect a `float` not to exactly encode `2147483638` (which is 2**32)?

Comment: Because when float is encoded we use IEEE 754 standard which is consisted of 32 bits, first bit is used for sign of number, next eight bits are used for bias + 127 and the rest is mantissa. Mantissa is using 23 bits of number's normalized form. In this case when you get normalized number you will see that you have 30 numbers that can go to mantissa, so you lose 7 numbers of your number. That was my way of thinking about it and I'm not sure if it correct one!

Answer (score 2):

That is the way that `float` works on your system.

Note that the C standard is intentionally flexible as to the type and sizes of the floating point types. A `float` does **not** have to be an IEEE754 32 bit floating point type.

Comment: No, it's capable of representing 2147483648 exactly, but not 2147483638.

Comment: Oops. Should've gone to specsavers.

Comment: But why is that? Why did we lose data precison? Is it because of implicit data type conversion?

Thanks a lot for answer!